# Insert default values in duplicated array key/values

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a csv file that is structured in this way. It gives me the number of pagesviews by hour

```
 "00","ARTICLE 1",100
 "00","ARTICLE 2",50
 "00","ARTICLE 3",30
 "01","ARTICLE 1",40
 "01","ARTICLE 2",100
 "01","ARTICLE 4",200
 "02","ARTICLE 1",30
 "02","ARTICLE 2",40
 "02","ARTICLE 3",30
 "03","ARTICLE 5",30
```

I import the csv in my php code and i insert the contents in a mutidimensional array. When i var_dump my array this is what i get

```
Array
(
[00] => Array
    (
        [ARTICLE 1] => 100
        [ARTICLE 2] => 50
        [ARTICLE 3] => 30
    )

[01] => Array
    (
        [ARTICLE 1] => 40
        [ARTICLE 2] => 100
        [ARTICLE 4] => 200
    )

[02] => Array
    (
        [ARTICLE 1] => 30
        [ARTICLE 2] => 40
        [ARTICLE 3] => 30
    )

[03] => Array
    (
        [ARTICLE 5] => 30
    )

)
```

So my issue is "ARTICLE 4" was only viewed at "01" but i would like it to appear in the keys "00","02","03" with a default value of 0. The same for "ARTICLE 5" which only appears at key "03". I would like it to appear in keys "00","01","02","03","04"

AT the end, i would like to my array to appeear like this

```
Array
(
 [00] => Array
    (
        [ARTICLE 1] => 100
        [ARTICLE 2] => 50
        [ARTICLE 3] => 30 
        [ARTICLE 4] => 0
        [ARTICLE 5] => 0
    )

[01] => Array
    (
        [ARTICLE 1] => 40
        [ARTICLE 2] => 100
        [ARTICLE 3] => 0
        [ARTICLE 4] => 200
        [ARTICLE 5] => 0
    )

[02] => Array
    (
        [ARTICLE 1] => 30
        [ARTICLE 2] => 40
        [ARTICLE 3] => 30
        [ARTICLE 4] => 0
        [ARTICLE 5] => 0
    )

[03] => Array
    (
        [ARTICLE 1] => 0
        [ARTICLE 2] => 0
        [ARTICLE 3] => 0
        [ARTICLE 4] => 0
        [ARTICLE 5] => 30
    )

)
```

I have tried doing something like this but it's not working

```
foreach ($orig as $item) {
$new[] = $item;
$new[] = $item;

}
```

Can some one please help ?

UPDATE

I tried something like this

```
foreach ($articles as $article) 
{
$pageviews2[$article] = $pageviews;
}
```

Where $pageviews2 contains the contents of my csv file and the array articles is structured in this way

```
$articles = Array("00", "01", "02", "03","04","05");
```

And below is the resuly i obtain when i var_dump the $pageviews2 array

```
Array
(
[00] => Array
    (
        [00] => Array
            (
                [ARTICLE 1] => 100
                [ARTICLE 2] => 50
                [ARTICLE 3] => 30
            )

        [01] => Array
            (
                [ARTICLE 1] => 40
                [ARTICLE 2] => 100
                [ARTICLE 4] => 200
            )

        [02] => Array
            (
                [ARTICLE 1] => 30
                [ARTICLE 2] => 40
                [ARTICLE 3] => 30
            )

        [03] => Array
            (
                [ARTICLE 5] => 30
            )

    )

[01] => Array
    (
        [00] => Array
            (
                [ARTICLE 1] => 100
                [ARTICLE 2] => 50
                [ARTICLE 3] => 30
            )

        [01] => Array
            (
                [ARTICLE 1] => 40
                [ARTICLE 2] => 100
                [ARTICLE 4] => 200
            )

        [02] => Array
            (
                [ARTICLE 1] => 30
                [ARTICLE 2] => 40
                [ARTICLE 3] => 30
            )

        [03] => Array
            (
                [ARTICLE 5] => 30
            )

    )
```

Comment: It would be a better question if you provide some code that we can actually copy/paste to try (like a real array instead of the var_dump output). And also explain what you tried so far, what didn't work; your current code doesn't do much...

Answer (score 1):

The way I've typically dealt with this type of situation is as you've mentioned, pre-populating each "outer" elements with a set of known values.  This works under the assumption that you know exactly how many elements you want in the second dimension of the array, and that you know ahead of time how many elements will be in the first.  Here is some code to demonstrate:

```
$pageviews = array();
$articles = Array("00", "01", "02", "03");

$prepopulated = Array (
    "Article 1" => 0,
    "Article 2" => 0,
    "Article 3" => 0,
    "Article 4" => 0,
    "Article 5" => 0
);
```

You can then create a skeleton array before importing the csv:

```
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $pageviews[$article] = $prepopulated;
}
```

Then, when you import the data from the csv, all that you're doing is overwriting the default values in the skeleton array you just created:

```
if (($handle = fopen("pageviews.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $pageviews[$data[0]][$data[1]] = $data[2];
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: the problem is i can't tell in advance the number of times to be displayed in the second dimension of the array and i dont know how many elements will be in the first.
}

Comment: Ah.  I'll update the answer to include a more generic approach that will determine the range of the elements.